# Web server still detecting my old IP despite proxy

Tags: windows-7, proxy

I am running my crawler on sites. I was thinking that I should change my IP before running the crawler so that sites do not block me.  I tried the Proxy Switcher software, it worked great.

Then I visited the `http://whatismyip.com` to check.  But it showed my two IPs. It shows 'proxy detected'.

I would like to know what is the use of a proxy server if my original IP is still detected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are the proxy you are using sends the [`X-Forwarded-For`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) header.

> I was thinking that I should change my IP before running the crawler so that sites do not block me.

It sounds like you're inventing a solution to a problem that doesn't exist. If you don't want sites to block you, respect their `robots.txt`, don't crawl their sites every two seconds and you'll likely be fine.

As far as trying to hide behind 7 proxies etc, you might want to switching to a proxy that doesn't forward your IP (it's optional to do so), or a VPN.

> I would like to know what is the use of a proxy server if my original IP is still detected?

In a corporate environment they're used for caching and access control.

Comment: is there any example of proxy server which don't forward  my ip

Comment: @user191542 I believe some proxy lists have that information, whether each proxy is "anonymous" or not.